# ActiveX controls implementation differences in VB6 & python using win32com.

Tags: python, vb6, activex, win32com

I currently have a third party ActiveX controls that are designed to be used in VB6. I want to migrate the controls to python. I got win32com and I ran 'makepy.py -i' on the type library file. I understand how to Dispatch an executable container using win32com.client.Dispatch() method and then call subclasses. The container is called Sterling and will be running when calls to the object will be made, but I don't exclusively mention the container in VB code, so I figure it's not needed here either. All I have from those COMM objects is the type library, however, it all seems to work in VB6. This is the VB6 code that works and accesses the COM object after I add reference to Sterling.tlb type library:

```
' Declare ActiveX type library class
Public WithEvents m_STIQuote As STIQuote

Private Sub Form_Load()
......................................
    ' Create an instance of type library class  
    Set m_STIQuote = New STIQuote
......................................
 End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
......................................
    ' destroy type library class
    Set m_STIQuote = Nothing
......................................
End Sub

Private Sub btnMDX_Click()
    ' structSTIMdxRegEx is a structure that comes with ActiveX type library
    Dim inMDXInfo As structSTIMdxRegEx
    inMDXInfo.bstrExchanges = "N"
    inMDXInfo.bstrMsgTypes = ""
    inMDXInfo.bReg = True
    inMDXInfo.bAllSyms = True
    inMDXInfo.bNewOnly = False

    'Call method in ActiveX class with the structure provided as an input
    m_STIQuote.RegisterMdxEx inMDXInfo
End Sub

' Event handler provided by the library that receives class with data as an argument. 
Private Sub m_STIQuote_OnSTIQuoteUpdate(structQuoteUpdate As SterlingLib.structSTIQuoteUpdate)
    LogMsg "MDX|" & structQuoteUpdate.bstrSymbol & "|" & structQuoteUpdate.nMdxMsgType
End Sub
```

This is what I have in python so far, and it can't find _ISTIQuoteEvents class and structures from Record map:

```
import win32com.client
from win32com.client import gencache
gencache.EnsureModule('{C418ADDA-61CC-4854-B69E-87F8BF6D7A0E}', 0, 1, 0)

class myQuoteEvents(_ISTIQuoteEvents):
    def OnSTIQuoteUpdate(self, structQuoteUpdate=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        print_str = "MDX|" + structQuoteUpdate.bstrSymbol + "|" + structQuoteUpdate.nMdxMsgType
        print print_str

myQuote = win32com.client.DispatchWithEvents("STIQuote.STIQuote_ctrl.1", myQuoteEvents)

inMDXInfo = structSTIMdxRegEx()
inMDXInfo.bstrExchanges = "N"
inMDXInfo.bstrMsgTypes = ""
inMDXInfo.bReg = True
inMDXInfo.bAllSyms = True
inMDXInfo.bNewOnly = False

myQuote.RegisterMdxEx(inMDXInfo)
```

**_ISTIQuoteEvents** is a class in makepy generated wrapper, but for some reason it's not visible in the script. I called gencache, so I thought I should be able to see it, but the name is not recognized. **ISTIQuote** is a class derived from DispatchBaseClass, and is an interface class. **STIQuote** is a CoClassBaseClass derived class in a wrapper, and it contains ISTIQuote as interface & _ISTIQuoteEvents as events. The container app is the third party program running on the machine, so this code is only executed when the container is running. In COMM terminology its Sterling. Should Sterling. So STIQuote is a sub class of Sterling. Both **structQuoteUpdate** and **structSTIMdxRegEx** have only RecordMap entries with CLSID, but I do know the fields they contain from VB6 environment. I was wondering how I can extract them from the wrapper to access their data structures.

This is the python wrapper with only relevant info left from makepy.py:

```
# -*- coding: mbcs -*-
# Created by makepy.py version 0.5.01
# By python version 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
# From type library 'Sterling.tlb'
# On Tue Jun 02 17:08:01 2015
'Sterling 1.0 Type Library'
makepy_version = '0.5.01'
python_version = 0x2070af0

import win32com.client.CLSIDToClass, pythoncom, pywintypes
import win32com.client.util
from pywintypes import IID
from win32com.client import Dispatch

# The following 3 lines may need tweaking for the particular server
# Candidates are pythoncom.Missing, .Empty and .ArgNotFound
defaultNamedOptArg=pythoncom.Empty
defaultNamedNotOptArg=pythoncom.Empty
defaultUnnamedArg=pythoncom.Empty

CLSID = IID('{C418ADDA-61CC-4854-B69E-87F8BF6D7A0E}')
MajorVersion = 1
MinorVersion = 0
LibraryFlags = 8
LCID = 0x0

.......................................................

from win32com.client import DispatchBaseClass

.......................................................

class ISTIQuote(DispatchBaseClass):
    'ISTIQuote Interface'
    CLSID = IID('{F8D282CC-FEE7-45EC-A080-4276E43E8214}')
    coclass_clsid = IID('{8EB74552-C174-4D51-819B-9E65A8916273}')

.......................................................
    def RegisterMdxEx(self, pMdx=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        'method RegisterMdxEx'
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(27, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((36, 1),),pMdx
            )

    def RegisterQuote(self, bstrSymbol=defaultNamedNotOptArg, bstrExch=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
        'method RegisterQuote'
        return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((8, 1), (8, 1)),bstrSymbol
            , bstrExch)

..........................................................................

    _prop_map_get_ = {
        "AskPrice": (11, 2, (5, 0), (), "AskPrice", None),
        "AskSize": (13, 2, (3, 0), (), "AskSize", None),
        "BidPrice": (10, 2, (5, 0), (), "BidPrice", None),
        "BidSize": (12, 2, (3, 0), (), "BidSize", None),
        "DefaultAcct": (17, 2, (8, 0), (), "DefaultAcct", None),
        "DefaultDest": (19, 2, (8, 0), (), "DefaultDest", None),
        "DefaultQty": (16, 2, (3, 0), (), "DefaultQty", None),
        "Exch": (9, 2, (8, 0), (), "Exch", None),
        "LastPrice": (14, 2, (5, 0), (), "LastPrice", None),
        "LastSize": (20, 2, (3, 0), (), "LastSize", None),
        "Level": (21, 2, (3, 0), (), "Level", None),
        "Symbol": (8, 2, (8, 0), (), "Symbol", None),
        "UpdateID": (26, 2, (3, 0), (), "UpdateID", None),
    }
    _prop_map_put_ = {
        "AskPrice": ((11, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "AskSize": ((13, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "BidPrice": ((10, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "BidSize": ((12, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "DefaultAcct": ((17, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "DefaultDest": ((19, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "DefaultQty": ((16, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "Exch": ((9, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "LastPrice": ((14, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "LastSize": ((20, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "Level": ((21, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "Symbol": ((8, LCID, 4, 0),()),
        "UpdateID": ((26, LCID, 4, 0),()),
    }
    def __iter__(self):
        "Return a Python iterator for this object"
        try:
            ob = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(-4,LCID,3,(13, 10),())
        except pythoncom.error:
            raise TypeError("This object does not support enumeration")
        return win32com.client.util.Iterator(ob, None)

..........................................................................

class _ISTIQuoteEvents:
    '_ISTIQuoteEvents Interface'
    CLSID = CLSID_Sink = IID('{7482011F-7414-460B-92A8-693F1FDB8C27}')
    coclass_clsid = IID('{8EB74552-C174-4D51-819B-9E65A8916273}')
    _public_methods_ = [] # For COM Server support
    _dispid_to_func_ = {
               14 : "OnSTIL2Reply",
                1 : "OnSTIQuoteUpdate",
                9 : "OnSTIQuoteRqstXML",
               15 : "OnSTIL2ReplyXML",
                7 : "OnSTIQuoteUpdateXML",
               13 : "OnSTIL2UpdateXML",
                4 : "OnSTIQuoteRqst",
               12 : "OnSTIL2Update",
                3 : "OnSTIShutdown",
                8 : "OnSTIQuoteSnapXML",
               11 : "OnSTINewsUpdateXML",
               10 : "OnSTIGreeksUpdateXML",
                5 : "OnSTIGreeksUpdate",
                2 : "OnSTIQuoteSnap",
                6 : "OnSTINewsUpdate",
        }

    def __init__(self, oobj = None):
        if oobj is None:
            self._olecp = None
        else:
            import win32com.server.util
            from win32com.server.policy import EventHandlerPolicy
            cpc=oobj._oleobj_.QueryInterface(pythoncom.IID_IConnectionPointContainer)
            cp=cpc.FindConnectionPoint(self.CLSID_Sink)
            cookie=cp.Advise(win32com.server.util.wrap(self, usePolicy=EventHandlerPolicy))
            self._olecp,self._olecp_cookie = cp,cookie
    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.close()
        except pythoncom.com_error:
            pass
    def close(self):
        if self._olecp is not None:
            cp,cookie,self._olecp,self._olecp_cookie = self._olecp,self._olecp_cookie,None,None
            cp.Unadvise(cookie)
    def _query_interface_(self, iid):
        import win32com.server.util
        if iid==self.CLSID_Sink: return win32com.server.util.wrap(self)

    # Event Handlers
    # If you create handlers, they should have the following prototypes:
#   def OnSTIL2Reply(self, arrayL2Update=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
#       'method OnSTIL2ReplyStruct'
#   def OnSTIQuoteUpdate(self, structQuoteUpdate=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
#       'method OnSTIQuoteUpdateStruct'
#   def OnSTIQuoteRqstXML(self, bstrQuote=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
#       'method OnSTIQuoteRqstXML'
#   def OnSTIL2ReplyXML(self, bstrQuote=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
#       'method OnSTIL2ReplyXML'
#   def OnSTIQuoteUpdateXML(self, bstrQuote=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
#       'method OnSTIQuoteUpdateXML'
#   def OnSTIL2UpdateXML(self, bstrQuote=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
#       'method OnSTIL2UpdateXML'
#   def OnSTIQuoteRqst(self, structQuoteRqst=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
#       'method OnSTIQuoteRqstStruct'
#   def OnSTIL2Update(self, structL2Update=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
#       'method OnSTIL2UpdateStruct'
#   def OnSTIShutdown(self):
#       'method OnSTIShutdownStruct'
#   def OnSTIQuoteSnapXML(self, bstrQuote=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
#       'method OnSTIQuoteSnapXML'
#   def OnSTINewsUpdateXML(self, bstrQuote=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
#       'method OnSTINewsUpdateXML'
#   def OnSTIGreeksUpdateXML(self, bstrQuote=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
#       'method OnSTIGreeksUpdateXML'
#   def OnSTIGreeksUpdate(self, structGreeksUpdate=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
#       'method OnSTIGreeksUpdateStruct'
#   def OnSTIQuoteSnap(self, structQuoteSnap=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
#       'method OnSTIQuoteSnapStruct'
#   def OnSTINewsUpdate(self, structNewsUpdate=defaultNamedNotOptArg):
#       'method OnSTINewsUpdateStruct'

..........................................................................

from win32com.client import CoClassBaseClass

..........................................................................

class STIQuote(CoClassBaseClass): # A CoClass
    # STIQuote Class
    CLSID = IID('{8EB74552-C174-4D51-819B-9E65A8916273}')
    coclass_sources = [
        _ISTIQuoteEvents,
    ]
    default_source = _ISTIQuoteEvents
    coclass_interfaces = [
        ISTIQuote,
    ]
    default_interface = ISTIQuote

..........................................................................

ISTIQuote_vtables_dispatch_ = 1
ISTIQuote_vtables_ = [
    (( u'RegisterQuote' , u'bstrSymbol' , u'bstrExch' , ), 1, (1, (), [ (8, 1, None, None) , 
            (8, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 28 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'DeRegisterQuote' , u'bstrSymbol' , u'bstrExch' , ), 2, (2, (), [ (8, 1, None, None) , 
            (8, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 32 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'DeRegisterAllQuotes' , ), 3, (3, (), [ ], 1 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 36 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'RegisterForMdx' , u'bMdx' , ), 4, (4, (), [ (11, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 40 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'RegisterForAllMdx' , u'bMdx' , ), 5, (5, (), [ (11, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 44 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'GetQueueCount' , u'lCount' , ), 6, (6, (), [ (16387, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 48 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'SubmitQuote' , u'bstrKey' , u'RetVal' , ), 7, (7, (), [ (8, 1, None, None) , 
            (16387, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 52 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'Symbol' , u'pVal' , ), 8, (8, (), [ (16392, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 2 , 4 , 0 , 56 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'Symbol' , u'pVal' , ), 8, (8, (), [ (8, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 4 , 4 , 0 , 60 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'Exch' , u'pVal' , ), 9, (9, (), [ (16392, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 2 , 4 , 0 , 64 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'Exch' , u'pVal' , ), 9, (9, (), [ (8, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 4 , 4 , 0 , 68 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'BidPrice' , u'pVal' , ), 10, (10, (), [ (16389, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 2 , 4 , 0 , 72 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'BidPrice' , u'pVal' , ), 10, (10, (), [ (5, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 4 , 4 , 0 , 76 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'AskPrice' , u'pVal' , ), 11, (11, (), [ (16389, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 2 , 4 , 0 , 80 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'AskPrice' , u'pVal' , ), 11, (11, (), [ (5, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 4 , 4 , 0 , 84 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'BidSize' , u'pVal' , ), 12, (12, (), [ (16387, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 2 , 4 , 0 , 88 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'BidSize' , u'pVal' , ), 12, (12, (), [ (3, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 4 , 4 , 0 , 92 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'AskSize' , u'pVal' , ), 13, (13, (), [ (16387, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 2 , 4 , 0 , 96 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'AskSize' , u'pVal' , ), 13, (13, (), [ (3, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 4 , 4 , 0 , 100 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'LastPrice' , u'pVal' , ), 14, (14, (), [ (16389, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 2 , 4 , 0 , 104 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'LastPrice' , u'pVal' , ), 14, (14, (), [ (5, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 4 , 4 , 0 , 108 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'Destroy' , ), 15, (15, (), [ ], 1 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 112 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'DefaultQty' , u'pVal' , ), 16, (16, (), [ (16387, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 2 , 4 , 0 , 116 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'DefaultQty' , u'pVal' , ), 16, (16, (), [ (3, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 4 , 4 , 0 , 120 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'DefaultAcct' , u'pVal' , ), 17, (17, (), [ (16392, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 2 , 4 , 0 , 124 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'DefaultAcct' , u'pVal' , ), 17, (17, (), [ (8, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 4 , 4 , 0 , 128 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'SetTradesOnly' , u'bTrades' , ), 18, (18, (), [ (11, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 132 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'DefaultDest' , u'pVal' , ), 19, (19, (), [ (16392, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 2 , 4 , 0 , 136 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'DefaultDest' , u'pVal' , ), 19, (19, (), [ (8, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 4 , 4 , 0 , 140 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'LastSize' , u'pVal' , ), 20, (20, (), [ (16387, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 2 , 4 , 0 , 144 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'LastSize' , u'pVal' , ), 20, (20, (), [ (3, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 4 , 4 , 0 , 148 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'Level' , u'pVal' , ), 21, (21, (), [ (16387, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 2 , 4 , 0 , 152 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'Level' , u'pVal' , ), 21, (21, (), [ (3, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 4 , 4 , 0 , 156 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'SubmitQuoteStruct' , u'bstrKey' , u'pQuote' , u'RetVal' , ), 22, (22, (), [ 
            (8, 1, None, None) , (36, 1, None, None) , (16387, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 160 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'RegisterForAllNews' , u'bNews' , ), 23, (23, (), [ (11, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 164 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'RegisterForNewMdx' , u'bMdx' , u'bAllSyms' , ), 24, (24, (), [ (11, 1, None, None) , 
            (11, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 168 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'RegisterQuoteEx' , u'pQuote' , ), 25, (25, (), [ (36, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 172 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'UpdateID' , u'pVal' , ), 26, (26, (), [ (16387, 10, None, None) , ], 1 , 2 , 4 , 0 , 176 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'UpdateID' , u'pVal' , ), 26, (26, (), [ (3, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 4 , 4 , 0 , 180 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'RegisterMdxEx' , u'pMdx' , ), 27, (27, (), [ (36, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 184 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
    (( u'RegisterL2' , u'pL2' , ), 28, (28, (), [ (36, 1, None, None) , ], 1 , 1 , 4 , 0 , 188 , (3, 0, None, None) , 0 , )),
]

..........................................................................

RecordMap = {
    u'structSTIQuoteUpdate': '{5D4A5541-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIQuoteSnap': '{5D4A5543-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTITradeUpdate': '{5D4A5544-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIOrderUpdate': '{5D4A5545-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIOrderReject': '{5D4A5546-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIOrderConfirm': '{5D4A5547-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIPositionUpdate': '{5D4A5548-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIBookUpdate': '{5D4A5549-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTILink': '{5D4A5550-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIQuoteRqst': '{5D4A5551-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIGreeksUpdate': '{5D4A5552-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTINewsUpdate': '{5D4A5553-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIAcctUpdate': '{5D4A5554-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIOrderFilter': '{5D4A5555-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTITradeFilter': '{5D4A5556-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIDrop': '{5D4A5557-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIOrder': '{5D4A5558-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIQuoteRegEx': '{5D4A5559-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIMdxRegEx': '{5D4A5560-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTICancelAll': '{5D4A5561-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIL2Reg': '{5D4A5562-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
    u'structSTIL2Update': '{5D4A5563-619F-48AB-8E64-0CAB14A92F6F}',
}

CLSIDToClassMap = {
..........................................................................
    '{7482011F-7414-460B-92A8-693F1FDB8C27}' : _ISTIQuoteEvents,
    '{8EB74552-C174-4D51-819B-9E65A8916273}' : STIQuote,
..........................................................................
}
CLSIDToPackageMap = {}
win32com.client.CLSIDToClass.RegisterCLSIDsFromDict( CLSIDToClassMap )
VTablesToPackageMap = {}
VTablesToClassMap = {
    '{F8D282CC-FEE7-45EC-A080-4276E43E8214}' : 'ISTIQuote',
}


NamesToIIDMap = {
    'ISTIQuote' : '{F8D282CC-FEE7-45EC-A080-4276E43E8214}',
    '_ISTIQuoteEvents' : '{7482011F-7414-460B-92A8-693F1FDB8C27}',
}

win32com.client.constants.__dicts__.append(constants.__dict__)
```